# Is returning an XElement considered as bad practice in C# RESTful services?

Tags: c#, rest, xelement

I would like to return a highly customised xml but the serialization of my objects does not let me manipulate the xml format, or at least I could not do it. So I was thinking about returning an XElement since it is possible. Would that be considered as bad practice ? Most methods would return a XElement.

Comment: There's not enough detail to give a good answer. XML has been used as content type for applications using a RESTful architectural style but there is a lot more to REST than the encoding used for the transfer of information between a client and a server.

Comment: That looks like a wise enough answer to me ! Thanks